# Convert array of dicts to Pandas dataframe, and convert dataframe back to array of dicts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following array of dicts, and I create a Pandas dataframe out of it:

```
original_data = [
    {'group': 'group1', 'value': 100}, 
    {'group': 'group1', 'value': 25}, 
    {'group': 'group2', 'value': 77}, 
    {'group': 'group2', 'value': 123}, 
    {'group': 'group3', 'value': 44}
]

df = pd.DataFrame(original_data)
```

This is the resulting dataframe:

```
group  value
0  group1    100
1  group1     25
2  group2     77
3  group2    123
4  group3     44
```

The problem is when I try to get the original dict out of the dataset using `to_dict()`, because I get a completely different object:

```
df.to_dict()
{'group': {0: 'group1', 1: 'group1', 2: 'group2', 3: 'group2', 4: 'group3'}, 'value': {0: 100, 1: 25, 2: 77, 3: 123, 4: 44}}
```

How can I get the original dict used to construct the dataframe?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try `orient='records'`:

```
df.to_dict(orient='records')
```

Output:

```
[{'group': 'group1', 'value': 100},
 {'group': 'group1', 'value': 25},
 {'group': 'group2', 'value': 77},
 {'group': 'group2', 'value': 123},
 {'group': 'group3', 'value': 44}]
```